# Is it possible to have function object as an element

Tags: r, data.table

Short answer: yes, see the accepted reply.

---

I have the two `data.table` below.

```
stocks = data.table(Ticker = c('xx','xx','yy','yy'), Date = c(as.IDate("2000-01-01"), as.IDate("2000-01-02")), t = c(1.8, 3.5))
   Ticker       Date   t
1:     xx 2000-01-01 1.8
2:     xx 2000-01-02 3.5
3:     yy 2000-01-01 1.8
4:     yy 2000-01-02 3.5
tt = data.table(Date = c(as.IDate("2000-01-01"), as.IDate("2000-01-02")), t0 = c(1,2), t1 = c(2,3), t2 = c(3,4), y0 = c(10, 20), y1 = c(-20, -30), y2 = c(33,44))
         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2
1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33
2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44
```

For each row in `stocks`, I want to find the approximate `y` given `t`, based on linear interpolation of values in `tt`.

```
zz = tt[stocks, on = 'Date']
zz[, y.approx := approx(c(t0,t1,t2), c(y0,y1,y2), t)$y, by = 'Date,Ticker']
         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2 Ticker   t y.approx
1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     xx 1.8      -14
2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     xx 3.5        7
3: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     yy 1.8      -14
4: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     yy 3.5        7
```

The problem is that doing this way has lots of duplicate calculation. Ideally I want to define an `approxfun` for each day and apply it to each row in `stocks`. But datatable cannot take function objects as its element.

```
tt[, ff := approxfun(c(t0,t1,t2), c(y0,y1,y2)), by = Date]
Error in `[.data.table`(tt, , `:=`(ff, approxfun(c(t0, t1, t2), c(y0,  : 
  j evaluates to type 'closure'. Must evaluate to atomic vector or list.
```

My question is:

1. Is there a better way than doing `approx` on each row (and being slow)?
2. Is it possible for datatable to have function objects as its element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty easy to store functions in a `data.table` - you just need to put them in a list:

```
tt[, ff := .(list(approxfun(c(t0,t1,t2), c(y0,y1,y2)))), by = Date]
#         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2         ff
#1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33 <function>
#2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44 <function>

stocks[tt, y.approx := ff[[1]](t), on = 'Date', by = .EACHI]
stocks
#   Ticker       Date   t y.approx
#1:     xx 2000-01-01 1.8      -14
#2:     xx 2000-01-02 3.5        7
#3:     yy 2000-01-01 1.8      -14
#4:     yy 2000-01-02 3.5        7
```

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
> zz
         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2 Ticker   t
1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     xx 1.8
2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     xx 3.5
3: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     yy 1.8
4: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     yy 3.5

> zz[t0<=t & t<=t1, y.approx:={a=(t-t0)/(t1-t0); y0+a*(y1-y0)}]
> zz
         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2 Ticker   t y.approx
1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     xx 1.8      -14
2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     xx 3.5       NA
3: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     yy 1.8      -14
4: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     yy 3.5       NA

> zz[t1<=t & t<=t2, y.approx:={a=(t-t1)/(t2-t1); y1+a*(y2-y1)}]
> zz
         Date t0 t1 t2 y0  y1 y2 Ticker   t y.approx
1: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     xx 1.8      -14
2: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     xx 3.5        7
3: 2000-01-01  1  2  3 10 -20 33     yy 1.8      -14
4: 2000-01-02  2  3  4 20 -30 44     yy 3.5        7
>
```

Don't know how general you need it to be (how many columns you really have). But worth trying to vectorize like this to save the function call overhead by row. Several iterations of a `for` loop for number of time deltas (2 in this case) should be faster than looping by row (let us know if you go that way and need to generate the query dynamically for each time delta).

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think later I'll have a more complex approximation (than linear), so probably can't spell out like you did here.

Comment: @jf328 You could use `approx()` instead of the spelling out.  The main thing for efficiency is to do it in bulk; anything but a function call per row.

Answer (score 2):

We can hack it with a global list of functions and the superassignment operator:

```
x <- list();
invisible(tt[,{ x[[as.character(Date)]] <<- approxfun(c(t0,t1,t2),c(y0,y1,y2)); 0; },Date]);
x;
## $`2000-01-01`
## function (v)
## .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
## <bytecode: 0x602762000>
## <environment: 0x603118610>
##
## $`2000-01-02`
## function (v)
## .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
## <bytecode: 0x602762000>
## <environment: 0x60312c9d0>
##
stocks[,y.approx:=x[[as.character(Date)]](t),Date];
##    Ticker       Date   t y.approx
## 1:     xx 2000-01-01 1.8      -14
## 2:     xx 2000-01-02 3.5        7
## 3:     yy 2000-01-01 1.8      -14
## 4:     yy 2000-01-02 3.5        7
```

Comment: unnecessary hackiness